# Sort items based on to-many reference

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nssortdescriptor

i want to get itmes, based on a property at the reference items.

like i have some boxes and all of them have items in it and i want to see the boxes sorted by title (a,b,c,d,e) but the boxes with finished items first.

- box "a" (5 items)
- box "c" (2 items)
- box "e" (8 items)
- box "b" (0 items)
- box "d" (0 items)

i tried it with subquery but got not the right results.

i want to use NSFetchResultController because of updates during usage.

```
let sortDescriptors = [
NSSortDescriptor(key: "( SUBQUERY(items,$item,$item.finished == 0).@count > 0 )", ascending: false),
NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare))
]
```

Does have someone a idea how to solve this?

I also tried to use the sectionNameKeyPath but with

```
let sectionKeyPath = "(( items.finished == 0).@count > 0 )"
```

i got "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue"

Code:

```
extension ManagedBox {

@nonobjc open override class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    return NSFetchRequest<ManagedBox>(entityName: "ManagedBox") as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>;
}

@NSManaged public var paused: Bool
@NSManaged public var title: String?

@NSManaged public var items: NSSet?
}

extension ManagedItem {

@nonobjc open override class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    return NSFetchRequest<ManagedItem>(entityName: "ManagedItem") as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>;
}

@NSManaged public var finished: Bool
@NSManaged public var title: String?

@NSManaged var box: ManagedBox?
}
```

Comment: Please post code for your box class and how you implement the title or items

Answer (score 0):

With CoreData and the SQLite backing store, you can only sort by persistent attributes.  One solution would therefore be to add a new persistent `hasFinishedItems` attribute to your `ManagedBox` entity and to ensure you update this whenever the related `ManagedItems` are updated.

But I think a better solution would be to use TWO fetched results controllers: one to handle the `ManagedBox` objects *with* finished items, and another to handle those *without* finished items.  Both FRCs would be sorted using the `title` attribute, but one would have a predicate as follows:

```
SUBQUERY(items,$item,$item.finished == 0).@count > 0
```

and the other would have the complementary predicate:

```
SUBQUERY(items,$item,$item.finished == 0).@count == 0
```

Your tableView datasource/delegate methods would then need to have two sections, the first being populated using the first FRC, and the second being populated using the second FRC.  Similarly, the FRC delegate methods will need to ensure that changes triggered by the first FRC update section 0 of the tableView, whereas changes triggered by the second FRC update section 1.  Provided you are careful to remap the indexPath from the FRC to the correct indexPath for the TV (and vice versa), this should work OK.

Comment: the solution with two fetchresultcontroller may help. they work. but i dont know if there will be a memory limit to find all its boxes. i will test it

Comment: @JeanetteMüller You could specify a `fetchBatchSize` for the fetches underlying the FRC, to limit the number of Boxes loaded into memory.